# What is the space complexity of a function dependent on the number of leaf nodes in a Binary Tree?

Tags: c++, space-complexity

A Binary Tree:

```
class BinaryTree {
public:
  int value;
  BinaryTree *left;
  BinaryTree *right;

  BinaryTree(int value) {
    this->value = value;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
  }
};
```

A function:

```
vector<int> myFunc(BinaryTree *root) {
    vector<int> results;
    
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        results.push_back(root->value);
    }
    
    if(root->left != NULL){
        auto lResults = myFunc(root->left);
        for(auto& result : lResults){
            results.push_back(root->value + result);
        }
    }
    
    if(root->right != NULL){
        auto rResults = myFunc(root->right);
        for(auto& result : rResults){
            results.push_back(root->value + result);
        }
    }
    
  return results;
}
```

As you can see, space complexity of the function is dependent on the number of leaf nodes in the tree.

So what is the space complexity of this function?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks, that is very thoughtful and considerate of you.

Comment: please show your attempt on solve it and where you got stuck

Comment: Here space complexity can be defined as the size of the binary tree.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the actual structure of your binary tree. If you actively balance the tree, or if the tree tends to be balanced due to its use, the number of leaves of a binary tree is close to `n/2` with n the total number of nodes in the tree. Think about a tree with 31 nodes, it would have 1 as root (depth 0) 2 at depth 1 and `2^i` at depth i with all leaves at depth 4 so `2^4 == 16`. Note that if a binary tree is filled with random numbers, it typically tends to be roughly balanced.

However, if you insert a sorted array of numbers and do not actively balance the tree, it will only have a single leaf node. However, in that case the depth of the tree is O(n) and your function recurses n times resulting in O(n) space complexity.

So in conclusion, the space complexity would be O(n).

Comment: @GillesOttervanger balance or not, it would be `O(n)` space complexity for OP's function.

Comment: @appleapple you think so? If there would only exist left children in the tree, at each level of the recursion the size of the vectors would be at most 1 even if the tree contains millions of nodes. I would call that O(1) space complexity, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: In your case you recurse `n` times, so it needs `O(n)` space

Comment: @GillesOttervanger usually we also take stack space into account, anyway there is no possiblily to return a `O(n)` size vector and only have space complexity `O(1)`

Comment: I forgot about the cost of the recursion. Thanks guys, I have fixed my answer.